# Connect to a terminated ssh -X application

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg

On Ubuntu 16.04 I connect to a remote server including X-forwarding and compression enabled via `ssh`. Once, the connection is established, I launch a process whose GUI is forwarded to my client. When I terminate the `ssh` connection, the application keeps running. Is it possible to reconnect to the GUI of the running applicaction via `ssh -X`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X11 forwarding - grab windows of programs already running](https://superuser.com/questions/1264624/x11-forwarding-grab-windows-of-programs-already-running)