# X11 forwarding - grab windows of programs already running

Tags: linux, ssh

If I ssh into a machine, I can run graphical applications if I enable X11 forwarding - I run `gedit` from the command line, and gedit pops up as a window. My question is this: Is there a way to make a window pop up for applications that are already running?

Example: Suppose I have two machines, A and B. I open gedit on A, and type `some text` and leave. Then I ssh into A from B. If I run `gedit` I'll just spawn another process. Can I access the gedit process that's already running (with `some text`)? Or is this a job for vnc?

Comment: The problem is that once applications have opened a connection to anX server, you can't redirect that connection. So you have to introduce a means of redirection beforehand, e.g. with `xpra`, see answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really a solution to literal "grabbing windows of programs already running", but still…

Use [`xpra`](https://www.xpra.org/).

> On X11, it is also known as screen for X11: it allows you to run programs, usually on a remote host, direct their display to your local machine, and then to disconnect from these programs and reconnect from the same or another machine, without losing any state.
>
> […]
>
> Xpra also allows forwarding of sound, clipboard and printing services. 
>   Sessions can be accessed over SSH, or password protected over plain TCP sockets with or without SSL.

It has to be installed, configured and started beforehand, just like `screen` or `tmux` for console applications. You have to run your program via `xpra` in the first place, then you can do the magic of (re)connecting from different machines.

`xpra` is available as `xpra` package at least in Debian and Ubuntu. I have used it few times. The performance was better than for plain X forwarding.

Examples are [here](https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage). The following are from `man xpra` on my Kubuntu:

> ```
> xpra start :7
> ```
>
> Start an `xpra` server using display number `:7`.
>
> ```
> DISPLAY=:7 firefox
> ```
>
> Start `firefox` running inside the `xpra` server. Run this on the host where `xpra` was started or in terminal forwarded by `xpra`. No window will appear until you attach with `xpra attach`.

You run the above examples on your A. Then you can attach directly from A:

> ```
> xpra attach :7
> ```
>
> Attach to the `xpra` server that is using local display number `:7`. Any apps running on that server will appear on your screen.

or from your B:

> ```
> xpra attach ssh:foo@frodo:7
> ```
>
> Use `ssh` to attach to the `xpra` server that is running on machine `frodo` as user `foo` and using display `:7`.  Any apps running on that server will appear on your local screen.