# Non VNC and VNC $Display confusion

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, display-settings

I have an Ubuntu 16.06LTS system (let's call it Fred) that I use while sitting in front of it and on that same system I run a VNC server (FredVNC).  My problem is that when I've started an application in one environment (i.e. Fred), it ONLY runs in that environment.  For example, if I start Libre Office and work on a document at home on Fred, then leave the house and want to open a .doc file in an email I'm checking remotely via a VNC client connection (to FredVNC), that .doc file does not open within VNC, but rather on my local desktop...Fred.  I have to return HOME to see it.  Or (alternatively) I can kill -9 Libre Office, then open the application in VNC.  But then any open docs that were on Fred risk losing data.

What I would LIKE is a way to have two parallel instances of apps open up individually...so that I could be working in Libre Office in VNC, while simultaneously having Libre Office documents open on Fred.

I am assuming (perhaps naively) that there's a command line way to open up an instance of a program that will assign it to the VNC or the Fred Display.  I've tried searching for this and unfortunately am in a keyword nightmare.  Nothing seems to be selecting the right terms and I get totally off topic results.

If anyone knows what I need to do that would be hugely helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your VNC server creates a virtual desktop instead of providing the existing one (which is, I believe, more common behavior). Plus Libre Office uses a single "main" process per user. When you open an additional file, the new process detects the existing one, relies the job to it and exits. I guess the old process sticks to whichever display was right at the moment it started.

After you kill the old process, a new one can open a file and persist, becoming the "main" Libre Office process from now on. It uses the display *it* considers right.

I think you could reconfigure the VNC server to provide the existing desktop. On the other hand I guess you had your reasons to use a separate virtual desktop, so you may not want to change this.

> What I would LIKE is a way to have two parallel instances of apps open up individually...so that I could be working in Libre Office in VNC, while simultaneously having Libre Office documents open on Fred.

I don't know any way to make Libre Office ignore the old process running for the same user. There's a `--display` option but I cannot make it work.

See this question: [*X11 forwarding - grab windows of programs already running*](https://superuser.com/q/1264624/432690). My answer there introduces [`xpra`](https://xpra.org). If you run (the first) Libre Office with `xpra`, you will be able to attach to its window(s) from elsewhere.

See [what else you can do](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage). In my opinion the main advantage over VNC is the ability to choose the operation mode at the moment you connect. You can start a new desktop, clone an existing one, run a program or attach to a program already running with `xpra`. Quite flexible, I think.

In the worst case scenario you would get to your existing desktop only to gently close non-"`xpra`-ed" Libre Office windows without losing data. Then you would run Libre Office anew, this time with `xpra`, still from the remote client.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoughts -- yes, exactly, you have understood what's wrong or what I need to do.  It might be that xpra will help me prevent this issue, so I will look into it.  Not exactly what I want (there's no way to force Libre Office to run 2 instances??) but perhaps enough of a work around.

Comment: @confused There's a `--display` option (e.g. `lowriter --display :1`) but I cannot make it work. If it works for you then please write your own answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: How can I tell which display my VNC server is using?  I think it's the same, actually, based on the results of uname -n, that's the same whether I'm in VNC or not.  So maybe if I could simply start VNC running in a different $DISPLAY environment that would at least solve part of it?  Then I could try swriter --display :1 or something?

Comment: I've figured out my VNC $DISPLAY is :3.0 and my localhost is :0.0.  Can I tell a window to open in one versus the other?